# How FindRoot is implemented

Tags: equation-solving, implementation-details

I am trying to reproduce my mathematica code in java, the problem is that I use FindRoot to solve either equations or non linear systems of equations (3*3 speciically).

For example

```
f[x_] := Exp[-l]*l^x/x!;
FindRoot[Sum[f[i], {i, 0, 5}] == 0.45, {l, 5}]

Out[4]= {l -> 5.97316}
```

I am trying to figure out what numerical method is used by FindRoot in order to search Java for an already implemented library.

I suspect that Newton Raphson is used, but what happens with function's derivate?

Comment: The Documentation Center page `tutorial/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation#7441` in Version 11.2 says: "FindRoot uses a damped Newton's method, the secant method, and Brent's method." Good luck trying to port the proprietary internal implementation of `FindRoot` to a different language using that vague description!

Comment: This might be of interest: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationPlottingSearchData.html

Comment: Or more generally, the [Unconstrained Optimization Tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html).

Comment: Root finding is a fairly standard mathematical problem and you should have no problem finding a Java implementation of any of the common root finding algorithms. I would recommend you look for Brent's method because it's very stable. The only disadvantage is that it needs a bracket to start. You can look it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit thanks for your reply. Can I use it for systems too? I have found apache commons math library but its not straightforward, neither explains whether it solves systems or not.

Comment: It seems like the Mathematica implementation of Brent's method only works for univariate problems. Maybe someone somewhere came up with an extension to higher dimensions, but it doesn't seem like a common thing.